# Why doesn´t my pthread function print out what I have expected?

Tags: c, pthreads, printf

I´m new to thread programming and in the stage of learning thread programming in C.

This simple code compiles and run but I thought it would print out both "hello world" and the number 8, but it doesn´t. Does anybody know the reason for this?

```
void *threadfunc(void *input_data){  
    printf("Hello World");  
    long tid;  
    tid=(long)input_data;  
    printf("thread ID: &d", tid);  
    return NULL;  
    sleep(1);  
}  
int main(){  

    long t = 8;  
    int t1;  
    pthread_t thread_obj;  
    t1= pthread_create(&thread_obj, NULL,threadfunc, (void*)t);  
}*
```

Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: Welcome to SO. pleas take care of formulating your question title that it better presents the problem that you are facing.

Comment: Ok, I will do my best in the future, this was my first question so I am a little unexperienced. Any suggestions on how I should have formulated it so it would be more correct and accurate?

Comment: I suppose it's just a typo you made when producing a short example for the question, but if not: `printf` formats are marked with a `%`, not a `&`.

Comment: @Marit, you should have reduced it from the start, it finally doesn't has to do with threads at all. So reduce it to the smallest example, here e.g you could first call your `threadfunc` directly, see if it prints, etc. The question title mixes two thing which with high probability don't have anything to do with each other.

Answer (score 8):

First up you'll probably want to call [`pthread_join`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/pthread_join.html) after the `pthread_create` somewhere. If you don't and the main thread exits, there's a (pretty good) chance **the new thread won't get a chance to run**.

In other words, once a thread `exit`s, they all do - the process doesn't "wait" for other threads.

---

You might also want to add newlines to your `printf` calls.

Answer (score 3):

The program terminates at the end of the `main` function. Which in your program is right after you call `pthread_create`. Therefore the thread doesn't get a chance to run.

To give the thread a chance to run you will need to make the main function wait for the thread to complete. By calling `pthread_join`.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what the other say (give it a chance to print something before terminating), you are printing with the wrong format specifier an basically get the transfer of the variable to the thread wrong. Try

```
tid = *(long*)input_data;  
printf("thread ID: %ld\n", tid);
```

and call the thread function with `&t` instead of `(void*)t`. (`long` will not always be properly converted into a pointer.)

Comment: Thanks! Did the changes, both in the print format specifier and adding pthread_join(&thread_obj, (void**)&t) and the thread prints "&ld". Thought it would print "8"? Have a nice day!

Comment: @Marit See my comment on the question for why it prints `&ld`.

Answer (score 0):

You should pass the address of your local variable t
    t1= pthread_create(&thread_obj, NULL,threadfunc, (void*)&t);

and your thread function should be like this

```
void *threadfunc(void *input_data){  
printf("Hello World");  
long tid;  
tid=*(long *)input_data;  
printf("thread ID: %ld", tid);  
sleep(1);  
}
```

Comment: I´ve run thread with both 1) (void*)&t and 2) &t as the parameter to be passed to the function and it works with both options. What is the difference?

Comment: It will work with both options because you are basically passing a pointer which holds an address  and pointer is basically 4 bytes in a 32-bit system, no matter what it points to. But a good practice would be to typecast it to (void *) to avoid warnings.